# Change radio button name and value when submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, drupal-8

I'm using the Webform Module in Drupal 8 to send data to phpList:

```
<input type="radio" name="mitglied_" value="ja">
<input type="radio" name="mitglied_" value="nein">
```

The problem is that in order to send correct data to phpList the name attributes have to be different and the value has to be the same:

```
<input type="radio" name="list[1]" value="signup">
<input type="radio" name="list[2]" value="signup">
```

Webform doesn't allow radio buttons with different names and same value, so I'm searching for a way to change them when submitting.

Comment: why don't do this:- `<input type="radio" name="list[1]" value="signup">
<input type="radio" name="list[2]" value="signups">`  and in your code check     for both `signup` and `signups`. that will be more easy. no jquery needed. i am telling based on this:- https://www.drupal.org/node/827264

Comment: In which code you mean I should check? The problem is that the names also have to be the same, otherwise you can tick both radio buttons.

Comment: ideally radio button is used when you want to submit just one value (as only one will be selected from the group). You can may be have hidden fields to make it work - `<input type="radio" name="mitglied_" value="ja">
<input type="hidden" name="list[1]" value="ja"><input type="radio" name="mitglied_" value="ja">
<input type="radio" name="mitglied_" value="nein">
<input type="hidden" name="list[2]" value="nein">` or use checkboxes (with name list[1], list[2]..) instead of radio button and make them behave like radio button using jQuery

Comment: I already tried to make checkboxes, where one is deactivated when the other is ticked, but this is not what the user normally expects. Hm, maybe I could activate the hidden fields by conditional logic, depending what radio button is ticked. If this doesn't work I will make to radio groups with one option each and use some of the plenty jquery examples here...